# Local Git as autosave

Tags: linux, git, autosave

I would like a local GIT is my home directory to implement autosave to the repository that happens every five minutes.

I have two Questions:

1. Is this s sane thing to do?
2. How does one go about writing a script that implements this functionality for a specified set of directories in the home directory on linux?

The aim is to capture all the histories all the important files in my home directory automatically without any input from me. I can use this whenever I screw-up.

Comment: Autosaving would make sense on every file change (not just periodically), where combining git with inotify can be handy.

Answer (score 3):

Sanity is all relative!

I guess it depends on why you are backing up. If it's for hardware failure, then this won't work because the repository is in the same folder (/home/) so if the folder goes, the repo goes. Unless of course you are pushing it to a storage repo on another machine somewhere as the actual backup.

We do use git to store important things, especially research papers and PDF's, so we can easily share them.

You would write a `cron` job that runs a script every so often. Basically you would write a simple `bash` script that does a `git commit -a -m "commit message"` periodically in your folder. The tricky part is doing the `git add` on the new files that were created so they are tracked. You will likely need to do a `git status` and parse the output from it in your script to find the new files, then `git add` that list. Python may be the easiest way to do that. Then you register that with `cron.`

Google is your friend here, there are plenty of examples on how to register scripts with `cron`.

Comment: you don't need to parse anything because all the files will be added automatically...

Comment: (and if you do need to do that, use `git ls-files`, not `git status`)

Comment: @Igor Popov Thank you for the detailed answer. This was what I was looking for. I will investigate the tracking issue further.

Comment: You have to tell it what to add. Just typing `git add` throws an error. I guess you could do `git add .` if you wanted to.

Comment: Any chance someone has already written this script? I'm thinking of building out something like this: https://github.com/eaut/rsync-time-backup but for a local git repo, as described in the question.

Answer (score 3):

Write a shell script that would enter each directory you want and run

```
git add .
git commit -m "new change"
git push
```

and then use cron to run the script each 5 minutes.

Comment: If repository is also local, you don't need git push.

Comment: I wouldn't say `git add` because that would blindly add files for tracking. Just `commit -a`, and if you want to track something new `add` it explicitly.

Comment: `git add .` will commit generated files as well which is not expected.

Comment: Also, you need to notice deleted files and `git rm` them.

Comment: With the .gitignore file, you can tell it to not track most of the generated files or particular folders that you know things will go in that you don't want tracked. Ignoring .o files and .*~ (emacs temp files) would be essential, among others.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov The 'git add .' would track the new files created, doesnt it? Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I also have the carefully write the .gitignore file so that I am not tracking garbage files generated during say a compile. Thanks @tpg2114 .

Comment: Your better bet may be to make a few directories -- like `builds` or something and you have to train yourself to always do your compiling in there. Then just ignore that directory. So if you can consistently partition your usage, the `.gitignore` should be a little easier to manage.

Comment: @MilanBabuškov The repository is local so there is no need to push. Thanks

Comment: @tpg2114 I think .gitignore is flexible and easy to adapt if there are changes so I will use that solution. Thanks

Comment: @MilanBabuškov My apologies for not responding sooner. I was away from stack overflow for a while but your responses were very useful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Write a shell script to do the following

```
1) git status --u=no  //It gives you the files which are modified
2) Iterate through the file list from step 1 and do git add <file>
3) git commit -m "latest change <date:time>"
```

Schedule this script in cron.

Comment: Including the the change time in the comment is useful for tracking the changes over time. Thank you. Now I need to try out my script coding skills;).